# How do you set up a git validation hook that checks that pushes to master only contain linear history?

Tags: git

How do you set up a git validation hook that checks that pushes to master only contain linear history?

I am trying to set up my git commit history according to 
 https://hackernoon.com/how-the-creators-of-git-do-branches-e6fcc57270fb

I want to enforce that any new commits coming into the `master` branch are one of the following:

- simple individual commits, or
- a merge commit that is based off master

```
* d4ebb82 - simple commit(19 seconds ago) 
*   ec98801 - Merge branch 'cleanup' into 'master' (12 minutes ago) 
|\
| * d8662fa - Code cleanup (15 minutes ago) 
| * 43451c5 - work work 
| * 9adb77d - foo (18 minutes ago) 
|/
*   a2b0c82 - Some work
```

BUT NOT

- a merge commit that is not based off master (i.e. looks like spaghetti)

```
*   8453901 - Merge remote-tracking branch 'template/master' into dev (6 days ago) 
|\
| *   f2b61c1 - Merge branch 'feature/spring-vars' into 'master' (6 days ago) 
| |\
| | * db90956 - Added: environment vars (6 days ago) 
| |/
* |   0e06dcd - Merge remote-tracking branch 'template-stuff/master' into dev (6 days ago) 
|\ \
| |/
| *   38747d9 - Merge branch 'new-certs' into 'master' (6 days ago) 
| |\
| | * b36ca67 - added (6 days ago) 
| |/
* |
...
```

I'm looking for the script, I can expect it would be in either `update` or `pre-receive`